# AngularJS -- Bind ngModel to an object stored in a property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to populate programatically a list of inputs.

I have something like

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
<input ng-model="field.Binding" />
</div>

var Query = {
    Keywords: "Foo",
    Title: "Bar"
}

var Fields = [{
    Name: "Keywords",
    Binding: Query.Keywords
}, {
    Name: "Title",
    Binding: Query.Title
}];

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.fields = Fields;
    $scope.query = Query;
}
```

Non-working fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/52/
The string is copied when I start my view, but the two values do not update eachother.

Basicallyk I'd like to bind to an object specified by reference or by name e.g "Query.Keywords" and have the scope evaluate this at runtime -- but I am not having much luck.

As you can see in the fiddle, my values do not stay synchronized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Zack for steering me in the right direction.

At any rate, if you use a string value for the binding e.g

Field { Binding: "Foo"}

You can then bind to data[Field.Binding] and this will work just fine. My first example was not working because it was binding to the string value, not the property itself of my data.

Working fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/57/

```
function cQuery() {
    this.Keywords= "Foo";
    this.Title = "Bar";
}
var Query = new cQuery();
var Fields = [{
    Name: "Keyword Search",
    Binding: "Keywords"
}, {
    Name: "Title Search",
    Binding: "Title"
}];


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.blah = Object.keys(Query);
    $scope.fields = Fields;
    $scope.query = Query;
}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="field in fields">{{field.Name}}
        <input type="text" ng-model="query[field.Binding]" type="text" class="form-control" id="{{field.Id}}" /> {{field.Binding}}
    </div>Elsewhere...
    <input ng-model="query.Keywords"  type="text"/> {{query.Keywords}}
</div>
```

Comment: The part ```ng-model="query[field.Binding]"``` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I edited the way you looked at the data. Hopefully this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/42/

```
 Removed query, attached input directly to fields.
```

Comment: I updated my fiddle. The Query exists in a larger project and is basically a singleton I access parameters from.

Comment: Ok, do you need need to update the Query object? Or can you just update the fields object?

Comment: I need to update the query object. I am using "fields" to generate a bunch (like a hundred) of configurable query parameters in an ng-repeat loop

Comment: @Yablargo Try this out. http://jsfiddle.net/JjNcz/ . I think this might be a cleaner way of doing it if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I guess the array works where the direct value pointer doesn't. Makes sense